# Scatter plot with different text at each data point

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, scatter-plot, annotate

I am trying to make a scatter plot and annotate data points with different numbers from a list.
So, for example, I want to plot `y` vs `x` and annotate with corresponding numbers from `n`.

```
y = [2.56422, 3.77284, 3.52623, 3.51468, 3.02199]
x = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
n = [58, 651, 393, 203, 123]
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(z, y, fmt='o')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can also get scatter plot with tooltip labels on hover using the mpld3 library. https://mpld3.github.io/examples/scatter_tooltip.html

Answer (score 802, accepted):

I'm not aware of any plotting method which takes arrays or lists but you could use `annotate()` while iterating over the values in `n`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
y = [2.56422, 3.77284, 3.52623, 3.51468, 3.02199]
n = [58, 651, 393, 203, 123]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
```

There are a lot of formatting options for `annotate()`, see the [matplotlib website:](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html)

[image]

Comment: Works well on top of Seaborn `regplot`s without too much disruption, too.

Comment: @Rutger I use a pandas datframe and I somehow get a `KeyError`- so I guess a `dict()` object is expected? Is there any other way to label the data using `enumerate`, `annotate` and a pandas data frame?

Comment: @Rachel, You can use `for row in df.iterrows():`, and then access the values with `row['text'], row['x-coord']` etc. If you post a separate question i'll have a look at it.

Comment: @RutgerKassies Thanks, Rutger! I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41481153/how-to-label-bubble-chart-scatter-plot-with-column-from-pandas-dataframe

I fear that it may be to similar to this very question. But I can't work it out somehow. Thank you for your help!

Comment: For points that happen to be very close, is there any way to offset the annotations and draw lines pointing from the data points to the labels in order to nicely separate the otherwise overlapping labels?

Comment: @aviator, not built-in unfortunately. But see for example this using networkx's layout engine:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697108/1755432

Comment: Is it possible to shift the text relative to the data points?

Comment: @Ben, yes the annotate function has a `xytext=(x,y)` keyword that allows specifying the location of the text label. The default is the same as the point `xy=(x,y)`. For example:  
`ax.annotate(txt, xy=(z[i], y[i]), xytext=(z[i]+0.1, y[i]+0.1))`
That will also allow drawing lines arrows between the two locations. More info at:  
https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/text/annotations.html

Answer (score 69):

In case anyone is trying to apply the above solutions to a `.scatter()` instead of a `.subplot()`,

I tried running the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
y = [2.56422, 3.77284, 3.52623, 3.51468, 3.02199]
n = [58, 651, 393, 203, 123]

fig, ax = plt.scatter(x, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
```

But ran into errors stating "cannot unpack non-iterable PathCollection object", with the error specifically pointing at codeline fig, ax = plt.scatter(x, y)

I eventually solved the error using the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(x, y)

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    plt.annotate(txt, (x[i], y[i]))
```

I didn't expect there to be a difference between `.scatter()` and `.subplot()`
I should have known better.

Comment: I'm using this exact same code in one of my scripts (the second block here), but I'm met with an error message saying "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1", which is referring to "txt" in the annotate function. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That's because `plt.scatter` is not meant to create a `Figure` and an `Axes` like `plt.subplots()` does, but a `PathCollection` containing the scatter points. You are supposed to create the figure and axes beforehand.

Answer (score 46):

In versions earlier than matplotlib 2.0, `ax.scatter` is not necessary to plot text without markers. In version 2.0 you'll need `ax.scatter` to set the proper range and markers for text.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = [2.56422, 3.77284, 3.52623, 3.51468, 3.02199]
z = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
n = [58, 651, 393, 203, 123]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, (z[i], y[i]))
```

And in this [link](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/text3d_demo.html) you can find an example in 3d.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks for sharing this solution. Can you also share what the proper code is to set the size of the figure? Implementations such as `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))` aren't working as expected, in that that invoking this code doesn't actually change the size of the image. Looking forward to your assistance. Thanks!

Comment: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))

Answer (score 35):

You may also use `pyplot.text` (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)).

```
def plot_embeddings(M_reduced, word2Ind, words):
    """ 
        Plot in a scatterplot the embeddings of the words specified in the list "words".
        Include a label next to each point.
    """
    for word in words:
        x, y = M_reduced[word2Ind[word]]
        plt.scatter(x, y, marker='x', color='red')
        plt.text(x+.03, y+.03, word, fontsize=9)
    plt.show()

M_reduced_plot_test = np.array([[1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1], [-1, 1], [0, 0]])
word2Ind_plot_test = {'test1': 0, 'test2': 1, 'test3': 2, 'test4': 3, 'test5': 4}
words = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5']
plot_embeddings(M_reduced_plot_test, word2Ind_plot_test, words)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

I would love to add that you can even use arrows /text boxes to annotate the labels. Here is what I mean:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y = [2.56422, 3.77284, 3.52623, 3.51468, 3.02199]
z = [0.15, 0.3, 0.45, 0.6, 0.75]
n = [58, 651, 393, 203, 123]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(z, y)

ax.annotate(n[0], (z[0], y[0]), xytext=(z[0]+0.05, y[0]+0.3), 
    arrowprops=dict(facecolor='red', shrink=0.05))

ax.annotate(n[1], (z[1], y[1]), xytext=(z[1]-0.05, y[1]-0.3), 
    arrowprops = dict(  arrowstyle="->",
                        connectionstyle="angle3,angleA=0,angleB=-90"))

ax.annotate(n[2], (z[2], y[2]), xytext=(z[2]-0.05, y[2]-0.3), 
    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="wedge,tail_width=0.5", alpha=0.1))

ax.annotate(n[3], (z[3], y[3]), xytext=(z[3]+0.05, y[3]-0.2), 
    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="fancy"))

ax.annotate(n[4], (z[4], y[4]), xytext=(z[4]-0.1, y[4]-0.2),
    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", alpha=0.1), 
    arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle="simple"))

plt.show()
```

Which will generate the following graph:
[image]

Answer (score 16):

For limited set of values matplotlib is fine. But when you have lots of values the tooltip starts to overlap over other data points. But with limited space you can't ignore the values. Hence it's better to zoom out or zoom in.

Using plotly

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.tips()

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year==2007 and continent=='Americas'")


fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", text="country", log_x=True, size_max=100, color="lifeExp")
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
fig.update_layout(title_text='Life Expectency', title_x=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: what are you using here for inline zooming? It's not `mpld3`, is it?

Comment: imho, an animation at this speed adds nothing, a carefully designed fixed image would be less frustrating.

Answer (score 13):

Python 3.6+:

```
coordinates = [('a',1,2), ('b',3,4), ('c',5,6)]
for x in coordinates: plt.annotate(x[0], (x[1], x[2]))
```

Comment: At that point, why not do `coordinates = [('a',(1,2)), ('b',(3,4)), ('c',(5,6))]` and `plt.annotate(*x)`?

Answer (score 4):

This might be useful when you need individually annotate in different time (I mean, not in a single for loop)

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.annotate('your_lable', (x,y))
```

where `x` and `y` are the your *target coordinate* and type is float/int.

Answer (score 3):

As a one liner using list comprehension and numpy:

`[ax.annotate(x[0], (x[1], x[2])) for x in np.array([n,z,y]).T]`

setup is ditto to Rutger's answer.

Comment: Instead of a list comprehension, which creates a list of unwanted values, use something like `deque(..., maxlen=0)`.

Comment: or use a regular for loop like a normal person. List comprehension is amazing and powerful but it should not be used in this situation