# Matplotlib Scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I build a scatter plot using matplotlib and python2.7
Here is the code:

```
def parse_dataset(dataset):
     foo   = dataset[0]
     bar = dataset[3]
     baz  = dataset[4]
     fig=plt.figure()
     plt.xlabel('foo')
     plt.ylabel('bar')
     plt.title("foo--bar--baz")
     plt.scatter(foo,bar,color = 'r')
     #plt.savefig("test.png", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.5,dpi=100)
     plt.show()
    # plt.clf()
```

However, what I would like to do is the following:
Build a scatter plot for baz based on the x-axis(foo) and y-axis(bar)
that is, based on the x-axis and y-axis. i want the value of baz to be plotted as text next to the point.

Scatter plot on the one hand, only allows me to have two dimensions to be given.
I tried the `ax.plot(x,y,z)` which allows me to plot in three dimensions (which however doesn't serve my purpose).

Is there a way to plot `baz` based on the values on `foo` and `bar`

Example of data:

```
Foo Bar baz
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
10  11  12
```

For every foo and bar i want the value of baz to be plotted.

It is a normal scatter plot.

Comment: P.S: All the elements in the dataset are of the same length.

Comment: Could you post an example of your data and an example of how should be your plot?

Comment: what is baz? the value for a (x,y) point, or a z-coordinate for a (x,y,z) point?

Comment: The value for x,y point.

Comment: And how should the value be represented? size of the dot? color? text?

Comment: The value of Baz. :) Sorry for not answering in prior. :)

Comment: So for `(foo, bar, baz) = (1, 2, 3)`, you want the text "3" to appear at x/y coordinate `(1, 2)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point

This should do it!

Probably, I should work on the font size