# Improve updated speed in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to update a matrix text in dynamic by using animation function of matplotlib. But I found that if the data array is too large , the animation will become very very slow. Is there any way to improve it ?

```
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))

def updatefig(i):
  plt.cla()
  ax.grid()
  data = np.random.rand(50,50)
  ax.set_xticks(np.arange(data.shape[1]+1))
  ax.set_yticks(np.arange(data.shape[0]+1))
  for y in range(data.shape[0]):
    for x in range(data.shape[1]):
      plt.text(x + 0.5 , y + 0.5, '%.1f' % data[y, x],horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center',color='b',size = 6)
  plt.draw() 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig,interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Actually, I wants to create a heatmmap plot with data values like below link. But use annotations is the only way i could figure out.
[Heamap with values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWTBn.jpg)

Comment: Those are a lot of annotations.. you probably are not going to see much with 2500 points annotated in a single plot (unless the plot is huge and the data points are sparse). Anyway, I think matplotlib doesn't have a mechanism for that.. you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14434334/764322), but I believe the result will be the same. What is slowing down your animation is iterating over all your 2500 points in python.

Answer (score 0):

Find a workaround by import seaborn module.
But how to avoid the graph keep flashing

```py
from matplotlib import animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,20))
sns.set()

def updatefig(i):
  plt.clf()
  data = np.random.rand(10,10)
  sns.heatmap(data, annot=True, linewidths=.5,cbar=False)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig,interval=50)
plt.show()
```