# Matplotlib map and subplot with different text at each data point

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, geopandas

I am mapping some data, weather stations across London, and want to label each data point (the green points) with the names of the weather stations, for example, Bow, Westminster.
The map is created from a Geopandas dataframe, from the geometry column. Using this post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point`
I tried to annotate the text, but get the following error:
`TypeError: 'Point' object is not iterable`.

Here is the map as it currently looks:

[image: Weather station data - green points]

and here is the code:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 12))
ax.set_title('Plot of London Grid for Learning weather stations with London boroughs and locations of Urban Mind datapoints', fontsize = 15)

boroughs.plot(alpha=1,edgecolor='w', facecolor='gray', linewidth=0.1, ax=ax)
london_umdata_geo.plot(ax=ax, marker="o",color="red",markersize=10.0,alpha=1.0, legend=True) #1,015 UM datapoints in London
stations_geo.plot(ax=ax, marker="X",color='green',markersize=20.0,alpha=1.0,legend=True)


n = stations_geo['Station Name'].tolist()
for i, txt in enumerate(n):
    ax.annotate(txt, xy = stations_geo.loc[i,'geometry'])

plt.show()
```

The stations are the green points, other data points (which will not be labelled) are in red.

`stations_geo` is a GeoPandas dataframe, which contains a `geometry` column from which the points are plotted using matplotlib.

I am using a loop for the annotate method, supposedly to loop through the points in the geometry column and use these as the co-ordinates for the annotations, but matplotlib seems not to like the Point objects (which are Shapely points). However, these points are being used directly to create the green points in the first place, so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Any chance this can be made reproducible ([mcve])?

Comment: Hello, not sure quite how to send you the stations data which would make it so ... stations_geo is a GeoPandas dataframe with 4 columns: Station_Name, latitude (float), longitude (float) and geometry, which is a Shapely point in BNG coordinates. e.g.   Station_Name  Latitude  Longitude  geometry
0  Bellingham  51.436  -0.009  POINT (538488.73396071 172657.9218037352)
1  Belmont  51.346  -0.203  POINT (525250.3766155766 162301.1070065825)
2  Bow  51.528  -0.028  POINT (536892.6139878684 182852.743870542)
3  Brent  51.552  -0.231  POINT (522747.2053606602 185161.702351622)

Comment: Sorry, I have never been able to work out how to format data nicely in StackOverflow. Tables seem to be difficult. You don't need to worry about the data that generates the red points, (london_umdata_geo) as I don't need to annotate these. All help very much appreciated

Comment: I suppose the problem is unrelated to the actual stations, so it should be easily reproducible within a short snippet within the question.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, yes, please see above. Hope this helps. BNG = British National Grid whereas the latitude, longitude points in stations_geo are in UTC co-ordinates

Comment: This will require pandas, geopandas, and shapely libraries as well as matplotlib to work.

Comment: The above does not allow me to run the code. But I would try with something like `xy = stations_geo.loc[i,'geometry'].coords[0]`.

Comment: Hi @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this works, thank you :-) I'm not sure I understand though - please can you explain, or point me to the right section of the docs? I don't find matplotlib particularly user friendly, unfortunately. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest please add this as an answer rather than a comment, and then I can mark it as answered. Thanks :-)

Comment: This is not really a matplotlib problem. Matplotlib supports pure python ints and floats, lists of those and numpy arrays. For everything else you need to make sure to convert it to one of the aforementionned datatypes. Matplotlib cannot know what users have as datatypes, so not sure what we should change. But if you have any suggestion concerning user-friendlyness, I'm all ear.

Comment: But I updated the answer to give you a guideline on how to potentially solve such problems in the future. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the problem yourself (*"matplotlib seems not to like the Point objects (which are Shapely points)"*).

So when confronted with such a problem, you may use the documentation as follows.

1. Look at the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) about what you may supply to the `xy` argument of `annotate`.

   > `xy` : iterable
   >         Length 2 sequence specifying the (x,y) point to annotate
2. Look at the object you have. In cause of doubt, use `print(type(stations_geo.loc[i,'geometry']))`. It will show something like `shapely.geometry.Point`. Look at [the documentation of that object](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html).
3. Identify a way to convert the one to the other. In this case you'll find

   > Coordinate values are accessed via `coords`, `x`, `y`, and `z` properties.
4. Print `stations_geo.loc[i,'geometry'].coords`, it will be a list of (a single) tuple(s). 
   So in order to convert a single shapely `Point` to a python tuple, you would use its `.coords` attribute and take the first (and only) element from that list.

   ```
   xy = stations_geo.loc[i,'geometry'].coords[0]
   ```

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest - really helpful explanation