# how to label the scatter plot with a column vales in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a table with day, transaction numbers, and sales total,

```
     day        transactions       total
0    Friday         100           3400
1    Monday         120           4800
2    .
3    .
4    .
6    Wednesday      80            2900
```

I can only scatter plot the transaction and sales columns.

How can I add the label(Friday, Monday...) on the side of the seven points？

Comment: what is your code for scatter plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point)