# Matplotlib: How to add legend to each scatter?

Tags: python, matplotlib

There is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 
import seaborn as sns 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_iris(return_X_y=False)
X = data.data
y = data.target
    
names = data.feature_names 
target_names = data.target_names
columns=names+['target']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([X, y.reshape(-1,1)]), columns=columns) 
df.loc[df.target==0, 'target_names'] = 'setosa' 
df.loc[df.target==1, 'target_names'] = 'versicolor' 
df.loc[df.target==2, 'target_names'] = 'virginica'  
indexes = df.index.tolist()

fig,axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(12,8))
axes[0,0].scatter(indexes,df['sepal length (cm)'],c=y)
axes[0,1].scatter(indexes,df['sepal width (cm)'],c=y)
axes[1,0].scatter(indexes,df['petal length (cm)'],c=y)
axes[1,1].scatter(indexes,df['petal width (cm)'],c=y)
plt.show()
```

How to add legend to each scatter, where each item is value of y ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is no direct way of making the scatter with tags on each data point.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434334/8837809) suggests iterating over your data points and labels, once you have created the scatter plots:

```
for i, txt in enumerate(y):
    axes[0,0].annotate(txt, (indexes[i], df['sepal length (cm)'][i]))
    ...
```

You can look at formatting options [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.annotate).