# Adding labels to datapoints in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I have a pandas dataframe (db_USA) that I'm using to create a scatterplot.
I want to label each observation with the values in the "TIME" column.
The examples I've found use a list, and I've tried converting the columns im using in the code to lists but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for

```
plt.scatter(db_USA["Value"], db_USA["3M Change %"])
plt.axvline(x=100.0, color ="black")
plt.axhline(y=0.0, color="black")
plt.xlim(right=103)
for i, txt in enumerate(list(db_USA["TIME"])):
    plt.annotate(txt, (list(db_USA["Value"])[i],list(db_USA["LOCATION"])[i]))
plt.show()
```

This is the result I'm getting.

[image]

Any suggestions are welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: Watch this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14434334/4688639

Comment: And, Why do you plotting a figure based on something and annotating it based on something else? I mean, are not any differences between "3M Change %" and "LOCATION"?

Comment: Soroosh- I saw the example you reference but it uses lists instead of the panda dataframe.
If I try running the code without the conversion to lists I get the following error message:
"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead."

I don't understand the suggestion.

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose the problem without an MWE. As @SorooshNoorzad noted, it's unclear why the label is being placed at "LOCATION" and not "3M Change %". I tried to reproduce the problem with a fake data set and the code you posted worked without error, so the issue might have to do with the nature of the DataFrame.

Comment: @gil  Thank you for your response.  Mapping the correct column to the iteration fixed the problem.