# adding labels to a scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, scatter

I am trying to label each point on this scatter plot with its name. So far - all my annotations end up in the bottom left corner. [the plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4d2b.png) How can I label each point? I see that other question that is similar but that is the question I used to create this code that isn't working... I not very good with for loops. I am not sure I set this one up correctly and if so, why won't it get the well names from my df and plot them based on their lat/lon?

this is the code I have:

```
   from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

   f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(20,20))

   m = Basemap(llcrnrlon = 2.4,llcrnrlat =60.11,urcrnrlon=3.3,urcrnrlat=60.91,epsg = 5939, 
   resolution = 'h')

   lat = df['Latitude '].values
   lon = df['Longitude'].values
   wells = df['Well_Name'].values
   x,y = m(lon,lat)

   for i in range(len(lat)):
       plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', c= df.Over_Pressure_MPa, cmap = "inferno_r", s = 200 )



   for i, label in enumerate(wells):
       plt.annotate(label, (lat[i], lon[i]))



   m.drawmapboundary(fill_color=None)

   m.fillcontinents(color=None,lake_color='aqua')
   m.drawcoastlines()

   plt.colorbar(label=r'Over Pressure')


   plt.show()
```

Comment: Can it help? [Matplotlib scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/matplotlib-scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point)

Comment: Not exactly - I can't see how my code is different to that but my result is not the same

Comment: Maybe you need to change `lat[i], lon[i]` to `lon[i], lat[i]` here:

`plt.annotate(label, (lat[i], lon[i]))`

Comment: this gave me the error 'float obj is not callable'