# How do I label the peaks from scipy.signal.find_peaks with their value?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I can easily get [scipy.signal.find_peaks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) to plot peaks (example from the documentation):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = electrocardiogram()[2000:4000]

peaks, _ = find_peaks(x, distance=150)
np.diff(peaks)

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], '.')
plt.show()
```

[image]

And getting the values of peaks is also easy:

[image]

But how can I plot `x[peaks]` either in place of the dot or nearby?

I had expected `plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], x[peaks])` would have worked, but no.

Comment: Do you mean add text boxes with `x[peaks]` values on your plot? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point

Comment: That's a way of doing it but I'm surprised there isn't something more idiomatic.

Comment: Try `plt.text` function. Docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html

Answer (score 0):

The only workable solution I found was using the more [upvoted answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point) that J. Choi referenced

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(p, q)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 10)
for i, txt in enumerate(p):
    ax.annotate(txt, (p[i], q[i]))

plt.plot(x)
plt.plot(peaks, x[peaks], 'x')
plt.show()
```

Results in:
[image]