# Label a certain x,y data point on a validation curve

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, cross-validation

```
valid1 = plot_validation_curve(rand_search.best_estimator_, X_train, y_train,
                               cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5), param_range=np.arange(2,100,2),
                               param_name = 'max_depth', scoring='f1')
```

I am using the plot_validation_curve fxn from sklearn. Let's say I pick out a spot on the curve that I think is the best. Now I want to confirm the actual x, y values. How do I label the points on the curve itself? Thanks!

I tried to label data points as one would with matplotlib but it didnt work.

Comment: Is `plot_validation_curve` a function from sklearn? I can't find it in the documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/search.html?q=plot_validation_curve

Comment: no, that's a custom modification which essentially returns: fig, axes

https://github.com/fan-yang-md/codingnomads/blob/main/data-science-machine-learning-main/notebooks/plotting.py

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment it seems like the task is to label points on the matplotlib plot, when all the values are given (`param_range` as x-axis, `train_scores`, `test_scores` as y-axes).
You can check out this answer to add labelling [Scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432557/scatter-plot-with-different-text-at-each-data-point).

Based on the answer there adding this to your code will help to annotate train scores:

```
for i, param_val in enumerate(param_range):
    axes.annotate(param_val, (param_range[i], train_scores_mean[i]))
```

And the same goes for annotating the other curves.
You can also add x-values as text if needed.