# How to add tags for a data point in an image

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

With the following code, I plot a graph as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
gflops_a = [72.3, 74.5, 79.6, 82.5] 
model_a_ACC = [9.3, 9.7, 11.2, 14.2] 

gflops_b = [73.95, 75.2, 79.9, 82.8] 
model_b_ACC = [7.8, 8.3, 9.1, 9.9] 

gflops_c = [74.3, 76.9, 82.3, 84.5] 
Set_ACC = [7.1, 7.8, 8.8, 9.7] 


# Creating the line graph
plt.figure(figsize=(3.8, 2.8))
plt.plot (model_a_ACC, gflops_a, marker='o', linestyle='')
plt.plot(model_b_ACC, gflops_b, marker='^', linestyle='')
plt.plot(Set_ACC, gflops_c, marker='s', linestyle='')

# Adding titles and labels
plt.xlabel('G')
plt.ylabel('A')
#plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()


# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The current output is as follows

[image]

How can I add tags for each data point? similar to the following image.

[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: by *"adding tags for a **data point**"*, did you mean a series?  What are the rules to place the "*tag*"? Why not use a legend?

Comment: I mean for each data sample, that I have, I want to add a tag to display in the image.
For example 'gflops_a = [72.3, 74.5, 79.6, 82.5] 
model_a_ACC = [9.3, 9.7, 11.2, 14.2]'  There are 4 data samples. So I want a tag for each sample.

Comment: Or it can be called a series of tags for all the data samples.

Comment: Add a label to each plot `plt.plot (model_a_ACC, gflops_a, marker='o', linestyle='', label='Sample 3')` and put `plt.legend()` after all the plot calls.

Comment: If you actually want to label each point then you can use [Scatter plot with different text at each data point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14432557/7758804), but I don't think this is desired